# Custom Field in Featured image for A particular post

Tags: posts, custom-field, pages, post-thumbnails

I have added a custom textarea to my featured image only to post, Using the following code.

```
function add_featured_description( $content ) {
    global $post;
    $small_description = get_post_meta( $post->ID,'thumbnail_description', true ) !== '0' ? get_post_meta( $post->ID,'thumbnail_description', true ) : '';
    global $pagenow;
    if (is_admin() && ($pagenow == 'post-new.php' || $pagenow == 'post.php') && ( get_post_type()=='post' ) ) {
      return $content .= '<div id="thumb_desc_container">
                            <textarea name="thumbnail_description" id="thumbnail_description" rows="4" style="width:100%;">'.$small_description.'</textarea>
                            <p class="hide-if-no-js howto" id="set-post-thumbnail-desc">Enter the image description.</p>
                          </div>';
    } else{
      return $content;
    }
}
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'add_featured_description');
```

It works fine!!! This code shows the extra textarea only in POST. But when i selected a featured image `else` part is executed(only featured image is returned).
When adding an image `$pagenow` contains `admin-ajax.php` and `get_post_type()` is null. global variables `$post` produces a null value. What should i do now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that there are additional input arguments available for the [`admin_post_thumbnail_html`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_post_thumbnail_html/) filter callback, namely `$post->ID` and `$thumbnail_id`:

```
/**
 * Filters the admin post thumbnail HTML markup to return.
 *
 * @since 2.9.0
 * @since 3.5.0 Added the `$post_id` parameter.
 * @since 4.6.0 Added the `$thumbnail_id` parameter.
 *
 * @param string $content      Admin post thumbnail HTML markup.
 * @param int    $post_id      Post ID.
 * @param int    $thumbnail_id Thumbnail ID.
 */
 return apply_filters( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', $content, $post->ID, $thumbnail_id );
```

that's applied within the [`_wp_post_thumbnail_html()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/_wp_post_thumbnail_html/) function.

Here's an example how you can avoid the global post in your snippet, by using the `$post->ID` input argument instead:

```
function wpse250432_add_featured_description( $content, $post_id, $thumbnail_id ) {

    $small_description = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'thumbnail_description', true );

    // Target only the 'post' post type
    if ( 'post' === get_post_type( $post_id ) ) 
      $content .= '<div id="thumb_desc_container">...</div>'; // Edit

    return $content;
}
add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'wpse250432_add_featured_description', 10, 3 );
```

If you really need to restrict this filtering to the `post.php` and `post-new.php` screens and the `get-post-thumbnail-html` ajax call, then you could add a check like:

```
if( 
       ! did_action( 'load-post.php' ) 
    && ! did_action( 'load-post-new.php' ) 
    && ! did_action( 'wp_ajax_get-post-thumbnail-html' )
)
    return $content;
```

but then I assume you're e.g. calling the "private" `_wp_post_thumbnail_html()` core function elsewhere? But these (*underscored*) [private functions are not intended for use by plugin and theme developers, but only by other core functions](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category:Private_Functions).

Comment: Thanks it works! But when filter is `add_filter( 'admin_post_thumbnail_html', 'add_featured_description',  10, 3 );` the function 'add_featured_description' ->`function add_featured_description( $content, $post_id, $thumbnail_id )` shows error, when the function contains two parameters as `function add_featured_description( $content, $post_id )` it works fine.
It will be great if you add the meaning of the parameters 10 and 3. Thank you so much anyway :)

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you. The `10` here is the (default) *filter priority* and `3` is the number of *input arguments* for the filter callback. If the number of input arguments is `1` then we can only access `$content` within our filter callback. If it's `2` then we get access to both `$content` and `$post_id`. Note that I prefixed the filter callback, to avoid possible name collisions with such a general function name as `add_featured_description()`. PHP *namespaces* is a good alternative. @Kuttoozz